# SQL Server triggers if else statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

What is missing in this code? If I'm updating the status of worker and the deleted status is 6, it should only execute the first nested if statement, not in the second if else statement but in this scenario when i update the worker status even if the data that is deleted is 6 it execute the two if else statement.. Any help, or suggestions is a big help for me..

Here is my code

```
if exists(select * from inserted) and exists(select * from deleted)
begin
    select
        @Worker_id = ID,
        @StatusID = StatusID,
        @Date = GETDATE()
    from 
        inserted;

    select
        @oldStatusID = StatusID
    from 
        deleted;

    if(@StatusID <> @oldStatusID)
        if(@oldStatusID = 6)
            if(@StatusID = 1 or @StatusID = 2 or @StatusID = 3)
            begin
                select
                    @Description = FirstName + ' ' + LastName + ' has been Hired'
                from 
                    inserted; 

                EXEC sp_history @Worker_id,'HIRED',@Description,@Date
            end
            else if(@oldStatusID = 1 or @oldStatusID = 2 or @oldStatusID = 3 or @oldStatusID = 4 or @oldStatusID = 5 or @oldStatusID = 9)
                if(@StatusID = 1)
                begin
                    select
                        @Description = FirstName + ' ' + LastName + ' has changed its status into Laborer'
                    from 
                        inserted; 

                    EXEC sp_history @Worker_id,'CHANGED STATUS(laborer)',@Description,@Date
                end

                if(@StatusID = 2)
                begin
                    select
                        @Description = FirstName + ' ' + LastName + ' has changed its status into Main Office'
                    from inserted; 

                    EXEC sp_history @Worker_id,'CHANGED STATUS(main office)',@Description,@Date
                end

                if(@StatusID = 3)
                begin
                    select
                        @Description = FirstName + ' ' + LastName + ' has changed its status into Admin'
                    from inserted; 

                    EXEC sp_history @Worker_id,'CHANGED STATUS(admin)',@Description,@Date
                end

                if(@StatusID = 4)
                begin
                    select
                        @Description = FirstName + ' ' + LastName + ' has changed its status into Blocklisted'
                    from inserted; 

                    EXEC sp_history @Worker_id,'BLOCKLISTED',@Description,@Date
                end

                if(@StatusID = 5)
                begin
                    select
                        @Description = FirstName + ' ' + LastName + ' has changed its status into Terminated'
                    from inserted; 

                    EXEC sp_history @Worker_id,'TERMINATED',@Description,@Date
                end

                if(@StatusID = 9)
                begin
                    select
                        @Description = FirstName + ' ' + LastName + ' has changed its status into Resigned'
                    from inserted; 

                    EXEC sp_history @Worker_id,'RESIGNED',@Description,@Date
                end
    end
```

Comment: This *looks* like [tag:sql-server] but we shouldn't *have* to guess. Please add an appropriate tag to your question since triggers are product-specific. If it *is* SQL Server, it's broken. There, triggers first once per *statement*, not once per row. That means `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. At the moment, you're ignoring the other potential rows, and, it should make you realise that if/else logic is also usually wrong since *some* rows may meet some condition and some rows not.

Comment: yes its sql server, so which line did i do wrong?

Comment: your basic concept of `inserted` and `deleted` in trigger is wrong. `inserted` and `deleted` table contains multiple rows that is affected from the `INSERT` or `UPDATE` or `DELETE` command. Your trigger code assumed only 1 row. which is wrong

Comment: I've already suggested the biggest problem - `inserted` can contain *multiple* rows. Look at everywhere where you're assigning variables values with statements that seem to assume that it only contains exactly one row. You have *lots* of them.

Comment: okay thanks for your answers :)